# How to detect if a web URL contains a feed or not?

Tags: browser, rss, feed, atom-feed

I have seen in some browsers (Firefox for example), the RSS feed icon gets activated only when a page contains a RSS/Atom feed. How the browser detects whether the page contains a feed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the code for this page.  You'll see this after some javascript in the header:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question 'How to detect if a web URL contains a feed or not?'" href="/feeds/question/3020295">
```

Alternatively, many blogs use

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Post Title" href="link-to-post">
```